# Is there a plan for coherence to support .net core projects?

Tags: caching, .net-core, oracle-coherence

I am creating a .Net core class library which I plan to publish as a Nuget package. As part of the requirement, I need to access a Oracle Coherence cache data source. Now Coherence dll doesn't seem to support .Net Core project at this moment. The .Net core application will run in non-windows environment. Has anybody faced a similar situation ? Does anybody know if Oracle Coherence is going to come up with .Net Core support ?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can integrate you .NET module to a Coherene Cluster with the Extended Client API  that are available in Java, .NET and C++.
I share with you the official doc:
https://docs.oracle.com/middleware/12213/coherence/develop-remote-clients/toc.htm

and .NET API:
https://docs.oracle.com/middleware/12213/coherence/net-reference/toc.htm